Vue JS event listeners don't work and vanilla work ( composition api+ script setup )
Problem: I created a custom component that works as a searchable selection which via vue's dom event handlers (@input, @focus, watch) detects client input and performs the search on the server.
My component works perfectly (maybe it could be perfected) on all devices except my phone (Xiamo Redmi 12) in which I use a custom keyboard for convenience. i thought that was the problem instead not.
Trying to detect the input with a vanilla javascript eventListener works while with vue handlers, the input is detected only when I 'unselect' the input.
<template>
<div ref="inputContainer" class="input-select-container" >
    <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
    <input 
      v-model="model" 
      :type 
      id="search-input"
      :placeholder 
      :required="required"
      @focus="handleShowList"  
      @input="handleShowList"
      autocomplete="off"
      :class="class"
    />
    <div class="input-select-list" v-if="insideList">
      <ul v-if="showList" ref="selectList">
        <slot></slot>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref, onUnmounted, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
  

  const model     = defineModel();
  const emits     = defineEmits(['show-list']);

  const props     = defineProps({
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'search'
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: 'input'
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    class: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    insideList: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  });

  const showList        = ref(false);
  const inputContainer  = ref(null);
  const selectList      = ref(null);


  function handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (inputContainer.value && !inputContainer.value.contains(event.target)) {
      handleHideList();
    }
  }

  function handleShowList(){
    showList.value = true;
  }

  function handleHideList(){
    showList.value = false;
  }
  //not work
  watch(showList, (value) => {
    emits('show-list', value);
  });
  //not work
  watch(model, (newValue, oldValue) => {
    console.log('Input value changed:', newValue); // Log per debug
    showList.value = true; // Mostra la lista ogni volta che l'input cambia
  });

  

  onMounted(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
    //WORK
    document.getElementById('search-input').addEventListener('input', function(){
      console.log('Input value changed:', this.value);
    });
  });

  onUnmounted(() => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
  });

  defineExpose({
    handleHideList
  });


</script>


Does it work properly on desktop? Do you see some errors in the devtools/console? Try to debug in a better environment first, then narrow it down to your phone afterwards.

yes, it works perfectly on any desktop, tablet and mobile device (android and ios), right on my phone it does not work, I tried to look with chrome devtools, reload the page without cache, and look at the console but it does not work

What browser is your Xiami on? If it works everything but there, it might be the renderer of the browser that does not work for some reason. Give a try to Firefox mobile maybe. There is no specific reason that it would not work tbh. Also, for further debugging maybe print the value to the template while testing on your phone by wrapping the emitted browser event to a template with some <pre> tags.

I tried every way, print from to screen, in the console, put the debugger on the input but nothing, with the vue listeners it doesn't work, by default I tried with chrome, with the xiaomi browser, with yandex and others, it's not a rendering problem because the page actually works, the input is not detected and that's it

I am not sure what Mi Browser is based on, but it's probably Chromium-based, same for Yandex. Hence why I recommended Firefox specifically. There is no specific reason that your mobile would be the only device where the code does not work. You could maybe play around with the Vue code just to be sure that it works well, but if it works everywhere else but your phone, then the issue is the hardware. I am not sure what kind of programs/scripts do run on those device, hence some research on reddit/forums would be recommended to find out a specific cause to the problem.

I just tried with firefox and the result is the same, now i try to change keypad and put the default android keyboard, anyway i thank you for all the advice

actually it is the yandex custom keyboard that doesn't work, I think it sends the text once you exit the writing mode, as if it keeps it for itself, I should try with other non-Gboard base keyboards and see if the effect is the same.
if my theory is correct, and the yandex keyboard loads the text once confirmed, however, I do not explain how it is possible for a vanilla eventListener, to pick up every single character typed.
in general i think i have solved it, thank you very much again for your help

Yeah, might be a weird way that the keyboard have to send the keystrokes. There is a wild west of non-standard practices by some of those. Swiftkey is a very good one on Android IMO.
